# How to load data into a table from a file and set other column(s) too?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, csv, datafile

I have a table with multiple columns. And there's also a text file which contains data, one value per line:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

How would I load a file into a file into a certain column as well as set other column?

```
+----+------+------+------+------------+
| id | col2 | col2 | col3 | created_at |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
|    |      |      |      |            |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
|    |      |      |      |            |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
|    |      |      |      |            |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
```

I want to load data from a file into `col2`, and set the column `created_at` to be `now()`.

===>

```
+----+------+------+------+------------+
| id | col2 | col2 | col3 | created_at |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
| 1  | aaa  |      |      | <timestamp>|
+----+------+------+------+------------+
| 2  | bbb  |      |      |<timestamp> |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
| 3  | ccc  |      |      |<timestamp> |
+----+------+------+------+------------+
```

How to do this via `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...`?

Comment: Why don't you format it with excel file and upload it via "Import"? That's easier and less time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other columns have `DEFAULTs`, then all you need is

```
LOAD FILE ...
    (col2);
```

You have implied that `id` is `INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, which is effectively a "default".

`created_at` can be specified to have the default `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

If you need something else, see the use of `SET` inside the `LOAD DATA` statement.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Since you need to manually set the date:

```
LOAD FILE
    ...   -- fill in as needed
    (col2)
    SET created_at = NOW();
```

Comment: The parens around the column list _are_ required.  Also I left out a lot of other clauses (`...`) that you probably need.